# ESXi/vSphere storage has free space but VMs suspend due to lack of space

Tags: vmware-esxi

A three node ESXi cluster is managed by vSphere. It uses a vSAN storage which comprises from directly attached disks of the ESXi hosts. The total capacity is ~6TB and vSphere clearly indicates that there is free space to the tune of several hundred gigabytes (I refreshed the storage capacity to validate).

However, VMs are being suspended by ESXi with this message:

> Message on vm001 on esxihost1.domain.com in XYZ: There is no more
> space for virtual disk 'vm001.vmdk'. You might be able to continue
> this session by freeing disk space on the relevant volume, and
> clicking Retry. Click Cancel to terminate this session.

Deleting some stuff from the vSAN and resuming the VM helps.

Why are VMs suspended when vSAN has free space?
ESXi host versions are  VMware ESXi, 6.5.0, 7967591

Comment: Seems like you're confusing vSphere for vCenter.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in rebalancing. Although total storage may be large enough, the storage in vSANs isn't always balanced so you might have disks that are full and some that aren't; vSAN free OTOH is aggregated. Basically vSAN isn't a linear raid.